# understanding syntax of boolean Graphics.drawImage()

Tags: java

In the function boolean Graphics.drawImage() why the result is to be boolean i mean what is the significance of boolean here can anybody tell me thanks in advance

Comment: Did you read the Javadoc?

Comment: yes but is not that satisfying so i think to get a satisfying answer i m studying trail from Javadoc only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `drawImage()` methods returns a `boolean`. Many people don't realize this, since the return value of `drawImage()` is often ignored. However, that `boolean` tells you whether or not the image was drawn successfully. If it was, `drawImage()` returns `true`. Otherwise `drawImage()` returns `false`.

Comment: When you write that the returned boolean tells whether or not the image was drawn successfully, you imply that `false` means failure. That's wrong.

Comment: yes but i guess it meant that if image is not fully drawn than it gives false

Comment: correctly if the job of drawing an image isn't completed somehow, the function will return `false`.